# Joining two a ViewModel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

This is the model:

```
public class ProCar
{

    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public int ProductYear { get; set; }

    public string CarBrand { get; set; }

    public int CarEngine { get; set; }

}
```

I'm using this LINQ. How to save to a List of ProCar.

```
List<Product> p1 = db.Products.ToList();
List<Car> c1 = db.Cars.ToList();
List<ProCar> query = from pList in p1 
join cList in c1 on pList equals cList.ProductId 
select new { ProductName = pList.ProductName, ProductYear = pList.ProductYear, CarBrand = cList.CarBrand, CarEngine = cList.CarEngine };
return View();
```

Cannot find the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have relation between `Product` and `Car` :

```
var query = from product in db.Products
            join car in db.Cars on product.Id equals car.ProductId//The relation between car and product
            select new ProCar
            {
                ProductName = product.ProductName,
                ProductYear = product.ProductYear,
                CarBrand = car.CarBrand,
                CarEngine = car.CarEngine
            };

List<ProCar> proCarList = query.ToList();
```

See [Join Clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause)

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an anonymous list type that is unable to find/cast List type of ProCar. So you need to specify for tightly couply model binding as below

```
List<ProCar> query = ( from pList in p1 
join cList in c1 on pList equals cList.ProductId 
select new ProCar
 {
       ProductName = product.ProductName,
       ProductYear = product.ProductYear,
       CarBrand = car.CarBrand,
       CarEngine = car.CarEngine
}).ToList();
```